Vscode not using the Python env when using source
In the Bash terminal in Vscode, I have a new env and I'm looking to use source to activate the env. But event when I do, the contents of the env are not being used.
I have pyenv but I don't call it at all in this process but the default is referring to the pyenv directory.
$ which pip
/Users/myprofile/.pyenv/shims/pip

$ which env/bin/pip
env/bin/pip

$ source env/bin/activate

(env) $ which pip
/Users/myprofile/.pyenv/shims/pip

This same process works fine and as intended when using terminal. With the following result:
(env) $ which pip
/Users/myprofile/env/bin/pip

I also checked my $PATH and in both Vscode and terminal, the env/bin directory is first entry as expected.
